# How to insert into a table from another table when both have two primary keys in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, connection

I have an identical table of applies on two databases. I have a link in one of databases to another one. I have filled up most of my data, except Applies table (So there is no error with insertion or connection):

The command I run is:

```
CREATE SYNONYM APP FOR Applies@"DB.DATA-PC10";
insert into Applies select *  from APP where APP.a# in  ( select a# from Applicant) and APP.p# in  ( select p# from Position);
```

The error I receive is:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01502: index 'BKG988.APPLICANT_PKEY' or partition of such index is in unusable state
```

I tried to disable PK temporary on both sides:

```
 alter table applies disable constraint applies_pkey;
 Table altered.
```

But still I get same error. Appreciate if anyone give me a solution:

```
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */ 
CREATE TABLE Applies(
a#      NUMBER(6)   NOT NULL, /* Applicant number       */
p#      NUMBER(8)   NOT NULL, /* Position number        */
appdate     DATE        NOT NULL, /* Application date       */
    CONSTRAINT Applies_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( a#, p# ), 
    CONSTRAINT Applies_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY ( a# )
                REFERENCES Applicant ( a# )
                ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT Applies_fkey2 FOREIGN KEY ( p# )
                REFERENCES Position ( p# ) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

and a table of Position:

```
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */ 
CREATE TABLE Position(
p#              NUMBER(8)       NOT NULL, /* Position number            */
ptitle          VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL, /* Position title             */
employer    VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL, /* Institution name           */
salary      NUMBER(9,2) NOT NULL, /* Salary         */
extras      VARCHAR(50)     , /* Extras         */
specification   LONG                , /* Specification      */
    CONSTRAINT Position_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( p# ),
    CONSTRAINT Position_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY ( ptitle )
                REFERENCES LPTitle ( title ) );
```

And here is table of applicant:

```
CREATE TABLE Applicant(
a#              NUMBER(6)       NOT NULL, /* Staff number               */
fname           VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL, /* First name                 */
lname       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, /* Last name          */
address         VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL, /* Street, home number, etc.  */
city        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, /* City           */
state       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, /* State          */
phone#      NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL, /* Phone number       */
fax#        NUMBER(10)      , /* Fax number         */
email       VARCHAR(50)     , /* E-mail address     */
acomment    LONG            ,  /* Interesting comments from interviews */
    CONSTRAINT Applicant_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( a# ),
    CONSTRAINT Applicant_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY ( state )
                REFERENCES LState ( state ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have found one solution which is:

```
/* Other option is to define the table DEFERRABLE  accrding to Q/A Tom in https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:8806498660292*/
Alter table applies disable constraint applies_pkey;
Alter table applies disable constraint Applies_fkey1;
Alter table applies disable constraint Applies_fkey2;

CREATE SYNONYM APP FOR Applies@"DB.DATA-PC10";
insert into Applies select *  from APP where APP.a# in  ( select a# from Applicant) and APP.p# in  ( select p# from Position);


Alter table applies enable constraint applies_pkey;
Alter table applies enable constraint Applies_fkey1;
Alter table applies enable constraint Applies_fkey2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with index rebuild first.

alter index BKG988.APPLICANT_PKEY rebuild online;

Then go with your insertion. If possible don't disable primary key. Or if you are not able to rebuild due to already having unique ids in the column then please remove first.